# How do I change the width of a tab during runtime in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

This shouldn't be that difficult.  I am looking in Microsoft's documentation and for an answer on the web.  Nothing.

I can find the documentation for C# but not VB.

I am currently doing this to hide all tabs expect the current one.  I then want to adjust the width of the tabs but for some reason Microsoft makes this so difficult.

```
Private Sub SwitchTab(ByVal SwitchTo, ByVal HideTab)

    Me.tcSalesforce.TabPages.Remove(HideTab)
    Me.tcSalesforce.TabPages.Add(SwitchTo)
    Me.tcSalesforce.SelectTab(SwitchTo)

End Sub
```

This is so simple to do in VBA, why is it so difficult in VB?

Comment: SO is about the facts. Just post the facts of your problem. Complaining that something is hard and is easier in some other language is irrelevant to the problem so does not belong in an SO question.

Comment: There isn't separate documentation for VB and C# when it comes to types and their members. The information is exactly the same regardless. There is a drop down at the top of the page to select the language for code examples. Most examples will be provided in both languages, although there will be some that are only provided in C#.

Comment: @jmcilhinney some pages do not have that drop down for switching to VB.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out:

Me.tcSalesforce.ItemSize = New Size(100, 20)